# play framework deployment on Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd

Tags: playframework, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, playframework-2.5, sbt-native-packager

When I follow the instructions for a deb-style deployment from the [official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying), I get the following error message on Ubuntu 16.04:

> Selecting previously unselected package my-app.
>   (Reading database ... 310635 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../my-app_1.0-SNAPSHOT_all.deb ...
>   Unpacking my-app (1.0-SNAPSHOT) ...
>   Setting up my-app (1.0-SNAPSHOT) ...
>   initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
>   Failed to start my-app.service: Unit my-app.service not found.
>   my-app could not be registered or started
>   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...

I assume this is because Upstart has been deprecated, but the build system is generating a deb that relies on Upstart. Is there some way to deploy using a deb file to Ubuntu 16.04 and have a working systemd service?

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.sbt`, add the following:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader

serverLoading in Debian := ServerLoader.Systemd
```

The generated `.deb` should now use SystemD instead of Upstart.

Answer (score 0):

Salem's answer is correct for pre 1.2.x . With 1.2.x and higher you'll have to enable the correct autoplugin to enable systemloader support.

```
enablePlugins(SystemdPlugin)
````

See the documentation for the available options:
packager.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0-m9/archetypes/systemloaders.html